# scalikejdbc - insert if not exists

Tags: scalikejdbc

How do I write the following code in ScalikeJDBC QueryDSL, or in the most elegant way available through ScalikeJDBC?

```
begin tran
if not exists (select * from T1 with (UPDLOCK) where c1=1 and c2=2 )
   insert into T1(c1,c2) values(1,2)
commit tran
```

Comment: Which sql implementation are you using?

Comment: Sorry, this is like 5 years old, so I don't remember. I believe it was PGSQL but don't remember which version.